# Exec Format Error from Rsyslog when executing a Python script

Tags: python, rsyslog

I am trying to execute a Python script from Rsyslog using the omprog module and I get the error:

```
omprog: failed to execute program '/path/to/script.py': Exec format error
```

How to successfully run the script from Rsyslog ?

The script works pretty fine and I have imported omprog module on my rsyslog.conf file. I have tried adding this line to my Python script `#!/usr/bin/env python` but nothing changed.

This line in rsyslog.conf is meant to execute the python script:

```
action(type="omprog" binary="/home/python_scripts/add_to_table.py" template="index")
```

Comment: It is perfectly possible to run a python script from rsyslog. Make sure you have provided execute permission on the file: `chmod a+rx /home/python_scripts/add_to_table.py`

Comment: It's not a permissions issue. All permissions are allocated. I think rsyslog can't find the right interpreter to execute the script since I get "Exec Format Error".

Comment: That message is the standard one for error `ENOEXEC` (see `man execve`). Try putting the full path to python at the start, eg `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Now it works after I added #!/usr/bin/python2. Thank you !